# Microsoft Access - use checkbox to save text from textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I´m making a register form in microsoft access and there is a text box to put the email.

At the end of the sign up form, there is a check box to check either the user wants to receive newsletter or not.

Just part of the form:
[image]

I want to be not checked by default and checked if the user wants.

How can i save the email from the textbox in a table?

Comment: Is this form set to be a pop up or a separate form, than to the one you use to create a register? In other words is this form related (BOUND) to the table you are trying to update?

Comment: @PaulFrancis This is the same form that I use to create a register. I just cut the other part to post here. The form is pop up though

Comment: Do you not normally save this email address regardless? The difference comes only when Querying all registered users who have opted for mailing list. Other than that I do not see any problem here.

Comment: @PaulFrancis The email is a primary key, can´t be null. This is my problem, I don´t know how to do the query for the check box. It does nothing right know.

Comment: You do not have to do anything. The Query for mailing list would be something as simple as `SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE yourCheckBoxField = True`. I hope the checkbox is bound to the field in the table you have based this form to.

Comment: @PaulFrancis I managed to make the checkbox work. It is working. Now, how can I make a form to bring this users that opted for mailing list. Showing all the information that are on the register form. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to do anything, as this form is bound to the table you are entering the information into. The Email address being the primary key will be entered as default. The checkbox is bound to the table too. So when the default value would be False, so you do not have to worry about it at all.

To display all of the information for the users who have opted for the mailing list. You first create a Query. The Query for mailing list would be something as simple as

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    yourTableName 
WHERE 
    yourCheckBoxField = True;
```

If you want to create a NewTable from this SELECT Query, use the following

```
SELECT 
    * 
INTO
    yourNewTableName
FROM 
    yourTableName 
WHERE 
    yourCheckBoxField = True;
```

Then give this a name say **qry_MailingListUsers**, then base this Query to create a Form, using the Form Design. Simple !

I hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks... It worked. But how can I create a table with this select? Because it created a query right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the default value to 0.
click the checkbox goto property pate > data tab >

```
control source = [your yes/no field in your table]
default value = 0
```